# Include a graphic as a character

Tags: fonts, symbols

I want to include a simple vector graphic (SVG, 1 circle and a path with 20 nodes) in the text, so it appears like a character.

[ifsym](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ifsym) does this with metafont, however metafont generates only bitmapped fonts.

My current solution is to create a new font with [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/), export it as OTF, include it with `\newfontface\foo{foo.otf}` and include it with `{\foo\symbol{1}}`.

This works (with XeLaTeX at least), however it is cumbersome and I need to distribute the font file every time I need to send someone the .tex-files.

How can I insert a simple vector graphic as a character into the text?

Comment: Convert the SVG into PDF and use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: The graphic might be used 200-300 times in the document and I'm not sure if it's included just once in the resulting pdf.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you really want to change a character into a graphic. Lets say the 'g'. I would make a Tikz-picture, and make the 'g' an active character that deletes the 'g' and inserts the Tikz-picture. -- If this is not what you want, please explain more thoroughly what you mean/want.

Comment: @tstenner It's included only once. If I include a 6KiB PDF file 100 times the PDF file is 13484 bytes; if I include it 500 times it becomes 14658 (`pdflatex`). With XeLaTeX I get 7186 bytes for 100 times and 10333 bytes for 500 times and

Comment: @jmc I have no problem including it with a macro, so using an active character is probably overkill. Tikz sounds interesting, I'll look into that.

Comment: @tstenner In that case I would define a macro which puts a TikZ-picture in the text. That is quite convenient. The `pgfmanual` (very very good) contains several examples of these inline graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following.

In your preamble include Ti*k*Z.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Also in the preamble, define a macro, e.g.,

```
\def\myGraphicChar{\tikz \node[chamfered rectangle, white, fill=red, double=red, draw, very thick]
   {\bf STOP!};
}
```

Next, in your text, just write `\myGraphicChar` where you want your graphic. All inline.

Comment: Looks great, I'll make myself familiar with TikZ.