# Create a character from pdf / svg that can change color

Tags: graphics, pdftex, symbols

Is it possible to create a charactar from a graphic that is sensible to `\color{}` commands? I'm aware of these three questions ([one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224357/182643), [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50223/182643), [three](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22487/182643)), but with the first method, the symbol doesn't change color, using TikZ is not feasable because the graphic is too complex, and creating my own font just for a few symbols seems overkill, and also will only work on machines that have the font installed. So is there an easier way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\mylogo{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{logo}}{X}}
\begin{document}
\color{orange} Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?

\tiny Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?
\end{document}
```

Comment: it depends on the graphic, in some cases it is possible to change their color, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150219/2388

Comment: I just found that same post. Thanks! But for some reason, it doesn't work for me even though the logo is just a back lines. One comment suggests for pdftex you could use the `resetcolor` argument for `\includegraphics` but if I try that, I get an error.

Comment: it doesn't matter which colors your graphics show but what it does internally.

Comment: So what does that mean? In what way to I have to save the graphics for it to work? The commenter says this works "only and only if the graphics does not contain color settings". I don't understand this.